# Android app name shows as "loading"

Tags: java, android, manifest

Hi I am working with android . I had created an app in which I used volley jar for loading json contents using the  link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/  . Here I am used a AppController class which extends Application.MY problem is that when I run the app in device it works fine but shows app label as "**Loading**". I dont know why this happens .I changed label and icon in manifest and so Icon will changes but app name still the same. Here is my manifest.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="info.androidhive.tabsswipe"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name="com.listview.myapp.app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_aloud"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Welcome"
        android:label="" >

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.ProfileView"
        android:label="" />

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Step1"
        android:label="" />

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Share"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Suggestion"
        android:label="" />

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Groupchat"
        android:label="" />

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivity"
        android:label=""
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Association"
        android:label="" />

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Asso_single"
        android:label="" />

    <activity android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.NotificationActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Step2"
        android:label="" />

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Step3"
        android:label="" />

    <activity
        android:name="info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Comment_thread"
        android:label="" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

here is my string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Testapp</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
     <string name="radio_public">public</string>
    <string name="radio_private">private</string>
</resources>
```

How can I solve this problem ? please help me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Look file res/values/strings.xml Here change variable app_name.

Comment: You should look at your `string.xml`, perhaps you set the app_name wrongly there.

Comment: check my edit..I tried this but i hope there is no issue regarding with string.xml

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what it is showing? i.e. app label being shown as 'Loading'

Answer (score 2):

Either remove  `android:label=""` from   `Welcome` activity or `android:lable="@string/app_name"` in `Welcome` activity .
Thanks